# Jquery position() include margin

Tags: javascript, jquery, position

If I want to include the margin when measuring the width of an element I may call `element.outerWidth(true);` However, I can't find a similar way to get the left offset of an element in a container, where the margin is included. `element.position().left` doesn't include margin.

I've tried `element[0].getBoundingClientRect().left`, and that works but is there a similar jquery call?

EDIT:
It seems that the native javascript call above doesn't give me the margin either..

Comment: [`.position()`](https://api.jquery.com/position/) does include margins, in the sense that it gives the position that the element's top and left margins extend to.  Whereas [.offset()](https://api.jquery.com/offset/) and [getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) do not include margins - they give the position/rectangle at the outer edge of the element's border.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is a limitation of jQuery's .position(), which has this limitation:

> **Note:** jQuery does not support getting the position coordinates of hidden elements or accounting for borders, margins, or padding set on the body element.

Recommended solution:

```
var position = $element.position();
x = position.left + parseInt($element.css('marginLeft'), 10);
y = position.top + parseInt($element.css('marginTop'), 10);
```

Comment: I assume the code in this answer works in some situations, but querying 'marginLeft' for me returns a string with the units suffix, e.g., "20px", so it needs to be converted. Assuming jQuery always returns margins in pixels, something like this will work:

    x = position.left + parseInt($element.css('marginLeft'))

Comment: Thanks @David, fixed.

Comment: Using a radix value in your parseInt calls is pointless in this situation (as it's default is 10 anyway) and makes this slightly harder to understand for noobs.

Comment: @David jQuery `.css()` will return the margin values in pixels (with `px` suffix), provided they do not have `display:none` or `display:contents`, regardless of how they are specified in the actual CSS, because internally it uses [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resolved_value).

Answer (score -3):

Use Jquery offset() function

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>offset demo</title>
  <style>
  p {
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Hello</p><p>2nd Paragraph</p>

<script>
var p = $( "p:last" );
var offset = p.offset();
p.html( "left: " + offset.left + ", top: " + offset.top );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: offset() function has the [same limitation](https://api.jquery.com/offset/) : _Note: jQuery does not support getting the offset coordinates of hidden elements or accounting for borders, margins, or padding set on the body element._